# Uploading MP3 file to Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to download an MP3 from an rss feed and then upload to an Amazon S3 bucket - I am very confident the XML is being parsed right and the file is being downloaded. I think the issue is in the upload part. Anyone have any insight into why this is not working?

ran multiple times trying to debug where issue is - also triple checked AWS permissions - my IAM account has full admin rights to S3

```
let parser = new Parser();
const fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var s3 = new AWS.S3();

parser.parseURL('https://bridgetown.podbean.com/feed.xml', (err, feed) =>
  request(feed.items[0].enclosure.url, function (err, response){
    uploadFileToS3(response, feed.items[0].title + '.mp3')
   }));

const uploadFileToS3 = (file, fileName, callback) => {
    s3.upload({ Bucket: bucketName, Key: fileName, Body: file }, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
          } else {
            console.log("Successfully uploaded data to " + bucketName );
            callback(data);
          }
  });

}
```

So I never get anything in console.log - so it makes me think there is an issue with the body: file parameter

Comment: forgot to put in my code - i do define bucketName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking the HTTP response object from `request` directly and trying to upload that as a file.

You should instead be taking the **response body** binary and uploading that. Use the third parameter of the `request` callback (`function (err, response, body)`) or parse the body yourself from the response object in case you are having trouble of getting the response in the correct data type (should probably be a `Buffer`, `Blob`, or `ReadableStream` in this case).

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense and what I was thinking after reading the SDK documentation that it wanted a binary object to be uploaded - I will try that later tonight and see what that does for me!